# Assign a particular ID to each item in a list and generate a new list with repeated IDs

Tags: python, list, zip

I have 2 lists, each have 5 items in them. But the items in the 'start' list are lists:

```
start = [[3606,5599,6312,7897], [2394], [84,1046], [1046], [1]]

id = ['AB022430', 'AB024537', 'AB043103', 'AB051349', 'AB051628']
```

I would like to created a new list with the format (I'm thinking via a pandas df or using 'zip'):

```
AB022430    3606
AB022430    5559
AB022430    6312
AB022430    7897
AB024537    2394
etc..
```

I essentially want repeating IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
[(ID, v) for ID, val in zip(id, start) for v in val]

#[('AB022430', 3606),
# ('AB022430', 5599),
# ('AB022430', 6312),
# ('AB022430', 7897),
# ('AB024537', 2394),
# ('AB043103', 84),
# ('AB043103', 1046),
# ('AB051349', 1046),
# ('AB051628', 1)]
```

Comment: Oh amazing! Can I do this with more than two lists?

Comment: Theoretically, yes. It depends on what you lists look like.

Comment: maybe something like this. `[(ID, v1, v2) for ID, val1, val2 in zip(id, start1, start2) for v1, v2 in zip(val1, val2)]`, say if start1 and start2 have the same structure.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you do

```
from itertools import chain

start = [[3606,5599,6312,7897], [2394], [84,1046], [1046], [1]]
id = ['AB022430', 'AB024537', 'AB043103', 'AB051349', 'AB051628']

chained_start = chain(*start) # Unpack the list and use 
# chain to "chain" the sub lists into a new one

ziped_info = zip(id, start) # Zip the lists together
```

Or in one line:

```
ziped_info = zip(id, chain(*start))
```